# How to use Zeppelin to access aws spark-ec2 cluster and s3 buckets

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I have an aws ec2 cluster setup by the spark-ec2 script.

I would like to configure Zeppelin so that I can write scala code locally on Zeppelin and run it on the cluster (via master). Furthermore I would like to be able to access my s3 buckets.

I followed [this guide](http://christopher5106.github.io/big/data/2015/07/03/iPython-Jupyter-Spark-Notebook-and-Zeppelin-comparison-for-big-data-in-scala-and-python-for-spark-clusters.html) and [this other one](http://sparktutorials.net/setup-your-zeppelin-notebook-for-data-science-in-apache-spark) however I can not seem to run scala code from zeppelin to my cluster.

I installed Zeppelin locally with

```
mvn install -DskipTests -Dspark.version=1.4.1 -Dhadoop.version=2.7.1
```

My security groups were set to both AmazonEC2FullAccess and AmazonS3FullAccess.

I edited the spark interpreter properties on the Zeppelin Webapp to *spark://.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:7077*
from local[*]

1. When I test out

   ```
   sc
   ```

   in the interpreter, I recieve this error

   ```
   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:182) at
   ```
2. When I try to edit "conf/zeppelin-site.xml" to change my port to 8082, no difference.

**NOTE:** I eventually would also want to access my s3 buckets with something like:

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "xxx")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey","xxx")
val file = "s3n://<<bucket>>/<<file>>"
val data = sc.textFile(file)
data.first
```

if any benevolent users have any advice (that wasn't already posted on StackOverflow) please let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your IP address is blocked from connecting to your spark cluster. You can try by launching the spark-shell pointing at that end point (or even just telnetting). To fix it you can log into your AWS account and change the firewall settings. Its also possible that it isn't pointed at the correct host (I'm assuming you removed the specific box from `spark://.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:7077` but if not there should be a bit for the .us-west-2). You can try ssh'ing to that machine and running netstat --tcp -l -n to see if its listening (or even just ps aux |grep java to see if Spark is running).

Comment: You were right! I simply needed to open the port in my EC2 Security Groups. Thank you!

Comment: great, glad to help :)