# Connecting S3 from Zeppelin using spark interpreter

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to do some basic analytics using Spark and Zeppelin.

I've set up the spark cluster using the steps present in [spark-ec2](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ec2-scripts.html)
Also I've set up the zeppelin in EC2 using the steps present in this [blog](http://christopher5106.github.io/big/data/2015/07/03/iPython-Jupyter-Spark-Notebook-and-Zeppelin-comparison-for-big-data-in-scala-and-python-for-spark-clusters.html)

I've add the libraries that I want to use using the below code in zeppelin notebook

```
%dep
z.reset()

// Add spark-csv package
z.load("com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.2.0")

// Add jars required for s3 access
z.load("org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.6.0")
```

And below code is to read CSV files from S3

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.impl","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId","XXX")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey","XXX")

val path = "s3n://XXX/XXX.csv"
val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").load(path)
```

I am getting the below exception

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack Exception Details: 
Location: org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3native/Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.initialize(Ljava/net/URI;Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;)V @38: invokespecial 
Reason: Type 'org/jets3t/service/security/AWSCredentials' (current frame, stack[3]) is not assignable to 'org/jets3t/service/security/ProviderCredentials' 

Current Frame: bci: @38 flags: { } 
locals: { 'org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3native/Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore', 'java/net/URI', 'org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration', 'org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3/S3Credentials', 'org/jets3t/service/security/AWSCredentials' } 

stack: { 'org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3native/Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore', uninitialized 32, uninitialized 32, 'org/jets3t/service/security/AWSCredentials' } 
Bytecode: 
0000000: bb00 0259 b700 034e 2d2b 2cb6 0004 bb00 0000010: 0559 2db6 0006 2db6 0007 b700 083a 042a 0000020: bb00 0959 1904 b700 0ab5 000b a700 0b3a 0000030: 042a 1904 b700 0d2a 2c12 0e03 b600 0fb5 0000040: 0010 2a2c 1211 1400 12b6 0014 1400 15b8 0000050: 0017 b500 182a 2c12 1914 0015 b600 1414 0000060: 0015 b800 17b5 001a 2a2c 121b b600 1cb5 0000070: 001d 2abb 001e 592b b600 1fb7 0020 b500 0000080: 21b1 
Exception Handler Table: bci [14, 44] => handler: 47 
Stackmap Table: full_frame(@47,{Object[#191],Object[#192],Object[#193],Object[#194]},{Object[#195]}) same_frame(@55) 
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem.createDefaultStore(NativeS3FileSystem.java:334) 
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem.initialize(NativeS3FileSystem.java:324) 
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2596) 
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
```

I've looked into [How to use Zeppelin to access aws spark-ec2 cluster and s3 buckets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557710/how-to-use-zeppelin-to-access-aws-spark-ec2-cluster-and-s3-buckets) 
As mentioned in the answer I've changed the security and able to connect with Spark. `sc.version` prints `1.4.0`

I've also looked into [Why Zeppelin notebook is not able to connect to S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30884662/why-zeppelin-notebook-is-not-able-to-connect-to-s3). In the answer it is stated to use local spark which I don't want to do. I want to use the spark cluster present in my EC2 instance.

What step that I miss here?

Answer (score 1):

The error you have happens due to **hadoop version mismatch** between compiled version inside zeppelin and the one available on your cluster in runtime.

You should check that Zeppelin [has been built with](https://github.com/apache/incubator-zeppelin#build) the flags, indicating proper version your cluster have.

Or you can try setting `HADOOP_HOME` env var pointing to the appropriate installation.

Comment: I've built it with hadoop 2.6.0 using the command ```mvn install -DskipTests -Dspark.version=1.4.0 -Dhadoop.version=2.6.0``` and I am using local Spark.

Comment: I've also tried by setting Spark home to external Spark instance with spark version 1.4 and hadoop version 2.6.0. Still getting the same issue